# Marker popup displayed outside Google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, if-statement, popup

I'm trying to make [this code by Geocodezip](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_infowindowOnMap.html) show only one popup at the time on the side of the map, the other(s) being hidden when not active.

I've tried to add an if..else statement to the google.maps.event.addListener for this but not working so far.

What should I do in the if..else statement to make all popups hidden unless active?

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
     if ( popup.dialog('open') ) {
         popup.show();
     } else {
         popup.hide();
     }

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

pass a unique id to the map marker, use that id to toggle the correct popup

```js
var popup = []


    addMarkerWithWindow("first","This is Lemans", new google.maps.LatLng(48.006922, 0.20874), map);
    addMarkerWithWindow("second","This is Paris", new google.maps.LatLng(48.856291, 2.352705), map);




    function addMarkerWithWindow(id, name, coordinate, map) {
/*    var popup=$('<div/>', {
      content: name
    });
*/
    var image = 'rss.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      // icon: image,
      position: coordinate
      customId:id
    });






//  jQuery 

    popup[id]=$('<div/>', {
    'id':'This is '+name,
    'text':'Hello World!'
    "class":'popp'

   }).dialog({
    'autoOpen':false,
    'width': 600,
    'height':600,
    'resizable':false,
    'modal':false,
    'title':name
   });


   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
    $('.popp').dialog('close');
    popup[this.customId].dialog('open');
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but I can't seem to get your suggestion to work. Could you place it in a working fiddle?